# C# - SetActive dont work?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, activation, gameobject

can someone tells me why my gameObject doesn't activate again?

Thanks.

**C# Code**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SlowerPowerUP : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (BirdMovement.CountFS > 300) {
            gameObject.SetActive(true);
        } 
        else {
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you rate my questuion negative then tell me why?!

Comment: You will need to add more relevant code, too many pieces are missing.

Comment: Please provide the expected behavior, any error messages when running the program, and all code related to the issue. If there is a lot of code, post it in a gist or pastebin file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deactivated objects are not receiving unity events (Update, FixedUpdate etc). So `gameObject.SetActive(true);` will not be called